# Show that $\sum _{k=0}^n \frac{k C_n^k\times!k}{n!}=n-1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, expected-value

I'm trying to solve this problem: $n$ people have $n$ different hats, put all the hats into a box, find the expected value of people that take the wrong hat. We have $n!$ cases, where the probability of $k$ people take the wrong hat (and other $n-k$ people take the correct hat) is $$\frac{!k\times C_n^k}{n!}$$
Where $!k=D_k$ is the derangement number. And the expected value is
$$
\sum _{k=0}^n k\times\frac{C_n^k\times!k}{n!}
$$
Mathematica told me that the value of this expression is $n-1$ for $n=\{1,2,\ldots,100\}$, how to prove it?

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to work out the expected number of people who take the RIGHT hat? Rephrase your formula and it should be pretty obvious. No need to bother with derangements I think.

Comment: If $k$ people take the right hat, then $(n-k)$ people will take the wrong hat, and the probability has a factor $D_{n-k}$, I can't find a method avoiding derangement.

Comment: Try induction...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left hand side clearly represent the expected number of people $\mathbb{E}(X)$ who take the **wrong hat**.

Call the expectation that person $i(=1,2,\ldots,n)$ takes the **wrong hat** $\mathbb{E}(X_i)$.

$X_i$ is the discrete random variable which is $1$ if $i$ takes the **wrong hat** and $0$ if he takes **his own hat**. The probability that $i$ takes **his own hat** is $\frac{1}{n}$ and the probability that he takes the **wrong hat** is $\frac{n-1}{n}$ hence:

$$\mathbb{E}(X_i)=\frac{1}{n}(0)+\frac{n-1}{n}(1)=\frac{n-1}{n}\, .$$

The discrete random variable for the **number of people** who take the **wrong hat** is clearly the sum of the random variables for individual cases $X_i$, viz:

$$X=X_1+X_2+\cdots +X_n\, .$$

So the expected number of people who take the **wrong hat** is

$$\mathbb{E}(X)=\mathbb{E}(X_1+X_2+\cdots +X_n)\, .$$

Then by linearity of expectation we have

$$\begin{align}\mathbb{E}(X)&=\mathbb{E}(X_1+X_2+\cdots +X_n)\\[1ex] &=\mathbb{E}(X_1)+\mathbb{E}(X_2)+\cdots +\mathbb{E}(X_n)\\[1ex] &=n\cdot\frac{n-1}{n}\\[1ex] &=n-1\, .\tag*{$\blacksquare$}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proof using  exponential generating functions.  The claim is
equivalent to  saying that the  expected number  of fixed points  in a
random permutation is one. This number is represented by the following
combinatorial class:

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\textsc{SET}(\mathcal{U}\times \textsc{CYC}_{=1}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \textsc{CYC}_{=2}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \textsc{CYC}_{=3}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \textsc{CYC}_{=4}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \cdots)$$

with EGF

$$G(z, u) =
\exp\left(uz +
\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^3}{3}+\frac{z^4}{4}+\cdots\right)$$

which is

$$\exp\left(uz  - z + \log\frac{1}{1-z} \right)
= \frac{\exp(uz)\exp(-z)}{1-z}.$$

We get for the expectation of the number of fixed points

$$[z^n] \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial u} G(z, u) \right|_{u=1}
\\ = [z^n] \left. z\frac{\exp(uz)\exp(-z)}{1-z} \right|_{u=1}
= [z^n] \frac{z}{1-z} = 1.$$

so there  is indeed one fixed  point on average and  $n-1$ people pick
the wrong hat.

As for an algebraic proof of

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} k \times !k = (n-1) \times n!$$

we use

$$!k = k! \sum_{q=0}^k \frac{(-1)^q}{q!}.$$

to get

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} k \times
k! \sum_{q=0}^k \frac{(-1)^q}{q!}
= \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} k \times
k! [z^k] \frac{\exp(-z)}{1-z}
\\ = n\sum_{k=1}^n {n-1\choose k-1} \times
k! [z^k] \frac{\exp(-z)}{1-z}
\\ = n \sum_{k=1}^n {n-1\choose k-1} \times
(k-1)! [z^{k-1}]
\left(-\frac{\exp(-z)}{1-z} + \frac{\exp(-z)}{(1-z)^2}\right)
\\ = n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose k} \times
k! [z^{k}]
\left(-\frac{\exp(-z)}{1-z} + \frac{\exp(-z)}{(1-z)^2}\right)
\\ = n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose k} \\ \times
k! [z^{k}]
\left(-\frac{\exp(-z)}{1-z} + \frac{\exp(-z)}{(1-z)^2}\right)
(n-1-k)! [z^{n-1-k}] \exp(z)
\\ = n \times (n-1)!
[z^{n-1}] \left(\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}-\frac{1}{1-z}\right)
\\ = n \times (n-1)!  (n-1)
= (n-1) \times n!.$$

This is the claim.